# angularjs filter with devider functionality

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I tried to implement a filter that returns a list as well as entries for divider. TextSearch should also be available with this filter.

Template:

```
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText" autocorrect="off" >

  <li class="item item-checkbox" 
        ng-repeat="destination in destinations |            (a)
                destinationFilter:searchText:true"          (b) 
        ng-class="destination.letter? 'item-divider':''">   (c)
```

- a iterate over the array destinations
- b use the custom filter
- c if the item comming from the filter has a letter-field, it's marked as divider

Filter:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
return function(input, key, startsWith) {
    if(input){
        var filteredInput = [];   (1)
        var lastChar = '';        (2)
        var re = /.*/i;           (3)
        if(key){                
            if(startsWith)        (4)
                key = "^"+key;
            re = new RegExp(key, "i");
        }
        for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
            var item = input[i];
            if(item.name.match(re)){                    (5)
                if(item.name.charAt(0) !== lastChar) {  (6) 
                  filteredInput.push({name:item.name.charAt(0),letter:true});
                  lastChar = item.name.charAt(0);
                }
                filteredInput.push(item);               (7)
            }
        };
        return filteredInput;                            
    }
    return input;    
};
});
```

- 1 array to contain the filtered list-elements from input
- 2 stores last divider character
- 3 regular expression to match everything
- 4 if statsWith -> only check reg expression from the beginning of the word
- 5 if the regular expression-match is successful -> push the item to the filteredInput
- 6 if last character matches actual item-firstChar dont generate a new list-divider-entry
- 7 push the item to the filteredInput array

Unfortunately this filter is called very often by a list of 30 elements. It also causes this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/infdig?
```

Divider are added for each element in the input I guess. It looks very odd.

FIDDLE: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/rwfj3jju/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your filter produces a new array each call, which leads angular to an [infinite loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

You better provide `ng-repeat` a constant array instead of a function (filter).
In your example it can be done simply by applying the filter in the controller instead of a view (your real world case might be different though):

```
$scope.filtered = $filter('destinationFilter')($scope.destinations, undefined, true);
```

In your html:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="destination in filtered" ng-class="destination.letter? 'item-divider':''" >
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2e8fhrd/).

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is going to work. All I have to do is to watch the searchText for changes ($scope.watch("searchText", ..)) and trigger the filter from the controller. Isn't it common to return a new array from a filter? I thought that's how they would work.

Comment: yeah thats a valid approach. the difference is that way during the dirty-check phase, angular will see a change the first time, but then it'll be the same on the second time, unlike the original approach which causes a change every time